# nodejs fs filesystem returns empty object

Tags: node.js

I am using require to require fs in my project

`var fs = require('fs')`

but when I do console.log(fs)`it gives me empty object`Object {}`

Why I am getting this ??

Also how can I get its methods ??

Comment: which node version you are using?

Comment: Are you using fs on a node server or are you trying to compile it for client-side usage with something like browserify/webpack?

Comment: can you open up the console/terminal and run: 
`$ node`  and when the node console opens then run
`require('fs');`

it should print out the fs object

Answer (score 0):

You do not get anything if you do `console.log(fs)` because of how the module is structured, There is no **default export** that is why you don't see anything when you console.log it.

Refer to the official documentation for a complete list of functions and APIs that File system has to offer here [File System Api Node js](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system)